# Adding a JComponent on top of full-screen-graphics

Tags: java, swing, button, canvas

I have a fullscreen program, which draws a lot of things for the game I am making. The canvas is the entire window, which it should be. Now I want to add a button, or textfield (JButton and JTextField etc...) to my window. However, when I add a button, or anything else, they go begind the canvas.

Do you have any idea how to get the button to show up ON the canvas, so I can click it?

Edit:
Drawing code:

```
public synchronized void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        if (!welcome)
            g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);

        if (welcome) {
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("images/backgroundWelcome.jpg")).getImage(), 0,0, null);
        }
        else if (gettingName) {
            setFont (new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 40));

            g.draw3DRect(center.x -325, center.y -50, 650, 100, true);
            g.drawString("Please enter your name", center.x -250, center.y -120);
            g.drawString(name, center.x -315, center.y);
        }
        if (game) {
            for (Player p: player) {
                int x = center.x;
                int y = center.y;

                switch (p.getID()) {
                case 1:
                    x -= name.length()*10;
                    y *= 1.4;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x -= name.length()*10;
                    y /= 1.4;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x *= 1.4;
                    x -= name.length()*10;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x *= 0.6;
                    x -= name.length()*10;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error 2");
                }
                g.drawString(p.getName(),x,y);
            }
            for (int x = 0; x<13; x++) {
                g.drawImage(diamonds[x].getImage(), (int) diamonds[x].getX(), (int) diamonds[x].getY(), null);
                g.drawImage(clubs[x].getImage(), (int) clubs[x].getX(), (int) clubs[x].getY(), null);
                g.drawImage(hearts[x].getImage(), (int) hearts[x].getX(), (int) hearts[x].getY(), null);
                g.drawImage(spades[x].getImage(), (int) spades[x].getX(), (int) spades[x].getY(), null);
            }
            g.drawImage(put.getImage(), (int) put.getX(), (int) put.getY(), null);
        }

        if (won) {
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("images/backgroundWelcome.jpg")).getImage(), 0,0, null);
        }
        else if (lost) {
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("images/backgroundWelcome.jpg")).getImage(), 0,0, null);
        }
    }
```

Edit2: 
My frame is a JFrame.

Comment: please provide relevant code.

Comment: I dont think the code is any relevant, but I'll add it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell much from the code snippet (please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) in future), but:

1. Don't code AWT in this millennium.
2. Don't mix Swing with AWT (at least until Java 7)
3. Don't load images within the `draw()` method (which is presumably called from the `paintComponent()` method).
4. Note that custom painting in Swing can be done in a `JComponent` or `JPanel` and that if the class is the latter, it can have a layout with other components added.

Comment: @mKorbel: If you *really* want to thank me, I'll accept a user report on my [File Manager questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110) thread.   Your comment on that thread is valuable, but a crash/bang test report would be much better.  (Yes, OK - I'm trolling for answers - please forgive me being pushy, & ignore me if I've overstepped the bounds of good manners).

Comment: Thanks. I added my code because the first comment told me to. I didn't think any code would be necessary. What code do you need, I'll remove the rest...
If I may ask, why should I not use AWT (and if I use it, why not in combination with Swing)? Until now I found it working well.

Comment: @Hidde: "What code do you need"  S-SC-C-E.  It is explained in the **link.**  "why should I not use AWT" It is a toolkit for last millennium.  Even if it is workable, few people can still remember AWT well enough to answer questions on it.  Most Java GUI developers entirely ignore questions about AWT. "why not in combination with Swing)?"  Search on "Java mix light heavyweight component".  The top 2 hits seem good.

Comment: I am looking into Swing instead of AWT, for example, I can't find any way to listen to mouse events with Swing. All the tutorials I find with google use AWT. Any suggestions (I am only into Java for two weeks, all learned with internet tutorials. No offence if I say stupid stuff). Thanks,.

Comment: @Hidde:  The trick is to include 'java tutorial' to the search string.  Those two searches would be 'events java tutorial' & 'gui java tutorial'.

Answer (score 2):

You are painting the canvas yourself so you will need to add the button elsewhere or paint an area that looks like a button and check if mouse events fall inside the button's area.

Comment: Yeah, I did that already, but I am very lazy, and the buttons don't look as good as normal buttons. I just wondered if there's a way to add a JButton.

Comment: You can use a normal buttons painting abilities. Just pass the Graphics to the paintComponent method of the button.

Comment: I'll look into that, for now I'll mark the question answered (I am getting somewhere with this). Thnx for the quick responses.